# How to embed Youtube & Vimeo videos in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: sxa

We are using `Sitecore 9.0 Update 2` and `SXA 1.7` and we want to have a feature to play Youtube,Vimeo & Facebook videos in a single component.

Is it possible to do this in SXA using the OOB components?

Comment: There is a contradiction, Youtube,Vimeo & Facebook videos are differently rendered, I am not sure, what type of component you want to create. Did you consider using the Rich Text Component and placing the Youtube,Vimeo & Facebook videos as iframes ???

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible in Sitecore SXA out of the box.

Sitecore SXA (Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.7.1) video component allows:

- Youtube video (you pass id)
- Movie in mp4 format:
- Movie in ogg format:
- Movie in WebM format:

Comment: https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-a-video.html

Answer (score 3):

I created a data template which allows a user to insert a URL and then display the link in an iframe.  The link could be single line text (as I have) but a general link field would also work.

[image]

Examples of this approach can be seen

https://portal.ct.gov/Office-of-the-Governor/Press-Room/Videos/Governor-Dannel-P-Malloys-2018-State-of-the-State-Address

https://portal.ct.gov/Business-Portal/Advanced-Manufacturing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible we have a component called `Video Gallery`.

**Steps:**

1) Drag & drop Gallery component from Media.

2) Then you have to click on '+' to add the Gallery Video which it supports both Vimeo & Youtube.

But the problem is it's a Video Carousal we can modify by using CSS based on our requirement.

Comment: OP is asking to use also Facebook video in one component. This is not fullfilling this requirement